# javascript how to stop current scroll

Tags: javascript

I have a page which is long enough to scroll on. On this page I have a button and when I click on that button it displays a `div` with `position fixed` and is also long enough to scroll. When I press esc the `div` closes.

The problem is that when I press esc (to close the `div`) while I am scrolling in that `div`, the scrolling continues on the page. I don't want to disable scrolling, I just want to stop that current scrolling. How do I do that?

Comment: did you try a `event.stopPropagation()` on the div you are closing, so the scroll event does not propagate to a parent node? (for a [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll))

Comment: I set `event.stopPrpagation();` before hiding it and it did not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: This is complicated because i guess it comes from the _smooth_ effect, so a dirty solution could be to keep in memory the last time your div has been scrolled, and then add an `eventListener` on the normal page which does a `event.preventDefault()` if your div has just been scrolled. This is dirty but it worked, i am interested to see if a better way exists...